# Math: Create lookup table for level assets when unlimited amount of levels

Tags: javascript, math, logic

I'm making a game that I plan on having an unlimited number of levels. Graphically the game has 20 different levels / assets, after that it starts at the beginning again but the score and level number still increments.

At the moment I just have a lookup where the logic is along the lines of...

```
if(gameLevel < 2){
    // set up assets for relevant levels
} else if(gameLevel< 5){
    // set up assets for relevant levels
} else if(gameLevel< 10){
    // set up assets for relevant levels
} else if(gameLevel< 15){
    // set up assets for relevant levels
}
```

I want the game to go back to using the assets for level 1- 4 during levels 21 - 24 and use assets from levels 5 - 9 for levels 25 - 29 and so on. But this needs to happen on an unlimited basis so a mathematical equation is needed rather than a simple lookup table.

I *think* I must use some modulo operation but so far It's not apparent to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modulo 20. Modulo assumes that you start at 0, so since our levels are numbered 1-20 (instead of 0-19), we need to adjust for that:

```
/* Returns the base level (1-20). */
int baseLevel(int level) {
    int noOfLevels = 20;  // You probably have this as a constant value in your code.
    return (level - 1) % noOfLevels + 1;
}
```

Your `if` statement then becomes:

```
if(baseLevel(gameLevel) < 2){
    // set up assets for relevant levels
} else if(baseLevel(gameLevel) < 5){
    // set up assets for relevant levels
} else if(baseLevel(gameLevel) < 10){
    // set up assets for relevant levels
} else if(baseLevel(gameLevel) < 15){
    // set up assets for relevant levels
}
```